# Permission problems with Clamfs

Tags: security, permissions, clamav

been trying to get [clamfs](http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/download/third-party-tools/3rdparty-fs/) working on Ubuntu 10.4. It seems like everything is working, clamfs locates infected files and prevents me from opening these.

But I am having permission troubles with a share that I have created.

My folder structure looks like this:

/.sharedfiles (this is the root directory for clamfs)

/sharedfiles (this is the actual shared folder on the server that my windows clients connect to).

When clamfs is NOT running, I can create and delete folders etc within ../sharedfiles from a windows client.

But when I turn clamfs ON I can only create files and folder immediately within ../sharedfiles.

ie I can create ../sharedfiles/newdirectory

But I can not create ../sharedfiles/newdirectory/somefile

I have played around with the permissions and ACLs but something is just not working.
I should mention that the windows clients are logging into the shared directory without a user. ie they are"nobody" and in the "nogroup" group.

I have set the ACL for both .sharedfiles and sharedfiles as below:

```
getfacl .sharedfiles/
# file: .sharedfiles/
# owner: administrator
# group: administrator
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx
default:user::rwx
default:user:clamav:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::rwx

getfacl sharedfiles/
# file: sharedfiles/
# owner: administrator
# group: administrator
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx
default:user::rwx
default:user:clamav:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::rwx
```

This is how I have configured my clamfs .xml file:

```
<filesystem root="/home/administrator/.sharedfiles" mountpoint="/home/administrator/sharedfiles" public="yes" readonly="no" nonempty="yes" />
```

Any idea on where I am going wrong? I would really like to get this working. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this may not be the exact answer to the problems I was running into, but it did solve the problem for me.

I have resolved to running clamfs as root which handled the permission problems I was running into.

I have setup clamfs as a startup script (which is run as root). To create the script and not have to manually do this each time I followed the tutorial [here](http://embraceubuntu.com/2005/09/07/adding-a-startup-script-to-be-run-at-bootup/):

> Write a script. put it in the /etc/init.d/ directory. Lets say you called it FOO. You then run
>       `% update-rc.d FOO defaults`
>   You also have to make the file you created, FOO, executable, using
>       `$chmod +x FOO`

I do not know all the implications here and maybe this is not correct. But I have a shared file now on a Ubuntu server that is accessible by all windows computers on the network without a user name or password, and has on-access scanning which prevents spreading viruses on the network (of which there are a ton right now). I like to think it is a sort of venus-fly trap =).

Hope this helps someone.